# Android Bitmpafun crashes at BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor

Tags: android, bitmap

I am using Bitmapfun application of android for loading bitmaps effectively.But sometimes a crash is occured at BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(). Log cat and function is given below.Crash occurs at the return statement. Please help me.Thanks in advance.

```
 public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromDescriptor(
        FileDescriptor fileDescriptor, int reqWidth, int reqHeight, ImageCache cache) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor, null, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    // If we're running on Honeycomb or newer, try to use inBitmap
    if (Utils.hasHoneycomb()) {
        addInBitmapOptions(options, cache);
    }

    return BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor, null, options);
}
```

Logcat

```
  06-25 14:20:56.055: E/AndroidRuntime(5978): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
06-25 14:20:56.055: E/AndroidRuntime(5978): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-25 14:20:56.055: E/AndroidRuntime(5978):     at com.vbk.vobok.util.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
06-25 14:20:56.055: E/AndroidRuntime(5978):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
06-25 14:20:56.055: E/AndroidRuntime(5978):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
06-25 14:20:56.055: E/AndroidRuntime(5978):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
06-25 14:20:56.055: E/AndroidRuntime(5978):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-25 14:20:56.055: E/AndroidRuntime(5978):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-25 14:20:56.055: E/AndroidRuntime(5978):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-25 14:20:56.055: E/AndroidRuntime(5978):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-25 14:20:56.055: E/AndroidRuntime(5978): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem decoding into existing bitmap
06-25 14:20:56.055: E/AndroidRuntime(5978):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(BitmapFactory.java:664)
06-25 14:20:56.055: E/AndroidRuntime(5978):     at com.vbk.vobok.util.ImageResizer.decodeSampledBitmapFromDescriptor(ImageResizer.java:196)
06-25 14:20:56.055: E/AndroidRuntime(5978):     at com.vbk.vobok.util.ImageFetcher.processBitmap(ImageFetcher.java:242)
06-25 14:20:56.055: E/AndroidRuntime(5978):     at com.vbk.vobok.util.ImageFetcher.processBitmap(ImageFetcher.java:255)
06-25 14:20:56.055: E/AndroidRuntime(5978):     at com.vbk.vobok.util.ImageWorker$BitmapWorkerTask.doInBackground(ImageWorker.java:326)
06-25 14:20:56.055: E/AndroidRuntime(5978):     at com.vbk.vobok.util.ImageWorker$BitmapWorkerTask.doInBackground(ImageWorker.java:1)
06-25 14:20:56.055: E/AndroidRuntime(5978):     at com.vbk.vobok.util.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:313)
06-25 14:20:56.055: E/AndroidRuntime(5978):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-25 14:20:56.055: E/AndroidRuntime(5978):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: Please help me.Application is not running.

Answer (score 4):

I had faced the same issue,
where in I deleted the method `addInBitmapOptions` at `ImageResizer.java`,and the bug was fixed.

Comment: This seems to be true. 
        if (Utils.hasHoneycomb()) {
            addInBitmapOptions(options, cache);
        }

I got crashes for devices running 4.x

Comment: the problem is - once the images have saved and cached on disk - it's safe to remove this line. however - on subsequently rebuilds (drag app to uninstall) - the images now won't load.

Answer (score 2):

I used BitMapFun and I'm sorry to tell you that this project is full of bugs. For instance in the AsyncTask they are doing setDrawable(..) not from UiThread and it's working as a Queue of WeakReferance. Meaning that if user scrolled down fast it will take long time until the user will see the images(depends on network strengh).

About your bug, in Android 2.1-2.3.7 there's a Dalvik VM GC bug that doesn't free allocated space in native heap. You must call recycle() on yur bitmap and setDrawable(null) on your imageView, with the call to System.gc() this bug should be solved. Let me know if I helped you. Cheers

Comment: I've been having this issue for ages, do you think you could help me out with it?

Comment: yes - download again the project(they updated him recently) and in the decode to bitmap function(ImageUtils.java) - set options with: o.inPurgeable;
o.inInputShareable;
It'll grant the GC more abillities in removing bitmap from native heap

Comment: I downloaded the most recent one today, but it says you need to open it in Android studio. When I first downloaded it, you didn't need Android studio to run it, but now you do for some odd reason

Comment: Sounds weird, it's just an android project - what matters the IDE?

Comment: I don't think so, try and download the latest one your self and use it with eclipse

Comment: Don't have time for it, in that case if you insist in working with eclipse - just open a new android project and copy the files(java + resource)..by the way - if you find my answers satisfing could you +1 me? thanks  :-)

Comment: Sure thing, hopefully I can get my problem solved =)

Answer (score 0):

I met the same situation with you. But, I was deliberately some data to produce this kind of situation. The reason is that I was specified

mImageFetcher = new ImageFetcher (getActivity (), 1024, 683);

I deliberately graphics memory is very big, beyond the memory of my set, I was hoping to detect image shows disorder, but does not appear, but the situation you have encountered. So I suggest you can compress images and set small scale to the img like that :

mImageFetcher = new ImageFetcher (getActivity (), 100,100);

Answer (score 0):

if your android sdk >= 4.0 (or above 4.0, i am not sure )is false, the options.inSampleSize must be 1.